# Align 3 stretched Textview in a row in Relative Layout prgramatically

Tags: android-layout, android-relativelayout, textview, android

Please don't mark this question as duplicate. Why? because I am going to explain why it's not.

Below are the steps I have done:

1. Create a RelativeLayout
2. Created LayoutPArams for it as wrap_content and wrap_content
3. Created 1st TextView , gave it an id
4. Created LayoutParams for first textview and added it to the RelativeLAyout
5. Created Second TextView
6. Created LayoutParams for it, added a rule to be right_Of of id_for_first_tetview
7. Same step for Third Textview, except it's right_of the second textview

The problem here is: The first text view has text which extends to the second line, and when the text extends to the second line, the width of this i.e. the first textview occupied the whole width, and hence the other textview either overlaps or comes below it. 
Let me demonstrate that with a diagram:

**Want:**

[image: This is what I want]

**Happening:**

[image]

So in short, is there a way to keep the textviews in one row and even if one textview takes up two rows, the second textview can start right after where the text for forst Textview ended ?

Thank you in advance. I could really use some help.

Comment: I think you can't achive that with relative layout. When you are setting wrap_content width for first textView, it will measure their width for their content (it will not break lines and will fill parent). Second textView , which will positioning at right of first will have strange width. To achieve what you want, it will be better to use LinearLayout with Layout_weight param for childs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did think of that, but the three textviews contain continuous text, so the user it seems like one big line, but in the source code, i want the text divided in 3 textviews. With the layout_width, the first textview will have wrapped content an it will not look continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with `LinearLayout` with `weight` easily.

**Method 1 - XML** (give required padding or margins)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextViewTextViewTextViewTextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Method 2 - Programmatically** (give required padding or margins)

```
tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
tv3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
tv4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);

android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);

tv2.setLayoutParams(params);
tv3.setLayoutParams(params);
tv4.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: well it did help me to a certain extent, but I want the text to be continuous, like it's one sentence. And this divides into three columns perfectly but it doesnot make the text continuous. i.e. first textview extends till middle of the second row and then the second text view starts from there and then goes till middle of third row and then the third textview's content starts there and goes till fourth line.

Comment: Also if you think to achieve what i want , i might be on the wrong path feel free to point that out and suggest another approach :)

Comment: Using the above approach I finally was able to do it , thanks :)
Though it's not possible to align the text in 3 textview as continuous line, until use of padding, which will break your UI on different devices.